# the number of checked checkboxes multiplied by 15 instead of fixed number on jquery counter?

Tags: jquery, counter

The code below works fine :

```
  $("label").click(function() {
var cntTo = 15 ;
//alert(cntTo);

counterUp.counter({
    autoStart: false,
    duration: 1000,
    countTo: cntTo,
    placeholder: 0,
    easing: "easeOutCubic",
    onStart: function() {

    },
    onComplete: function() {

    }
  });


counterUp.counter("start");
});
```

But by changing only one line, the code doesn't work

```
  $("label").click(function() {
var cntTo = 15 * $('span.checked').size();  /// CODE DOESNT WORK
//alert(cntTo);

counterUp.counter({
    autoStart: false,
    duration: 1000,
    countTo: cntTo,
    placeholder: 0,
    easing: "easeOutCubic",
    onStart: function() {

    },
    onComplete: function() {

    }
  });


counterUp.counter("start");
});
```

What really confuses me is that using line below to debug will correctly show the number I want to use, I tried to wrap it with parseInt but the counter doesnt work

```
 alert(15 * $('span.checked').size());
```

How can I assign to cntTo variable, the number of checked checkboxes multiplied by 15 ?

**SECOND METHOD DOESN'T WORK, COUNTER DOESN'T COUNT TO DESIRED NUMBER AND IT ALWAYS SHOWS 0**

Comment: can you show this in fiddle?

Comment: show us your html code.

Comment: First, `span.checked` selects those with the **class** of checked.  Use `:checked` to count those that **are** checked.  Second, no need for `.size()` - can use simply `.length`.  Finally, the reason it's not working is almost certainly because there are zero of the selected element - the selector is probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

try to set

```
 15 * parseInt($('span.checked').size())
```

Also to be sure, the error is not from datatype, and the not from $('span.checked').size(), change the 15 to 20 (for example), and then look is work ? ...